# Laplace transform of $-e^{bt}\sin(\omega _0 t)u(-t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that Laplace transform of $$e^{-\alpha t}\sin(\omega _0t)u(t)$$ is $\frac{\omega _0}{(s+\alpha )^2+\omega _0^2}$ where $Re(s)>-Re(\alpha )$ and $u(t)=\boldsymbol 1_{t\geq 0}$. Knowing that, how can I find the Laplace transform of $$-e^{bt}\sin(\omega _0t)u(-t) \ \ ?$$

I know it's $\frac{\omega _0}{(s-b)^2+\omega _0^2}$ for $Re(s)<b$, but I really don't know how to get that. I tried to use the fact that $$-e^{bt}\sin(\omega _0t)u(-t)=e^{-(-b)t}\sin(\omega _0 t)\underbrace{(1-u(-t))}_{=\boldsymbol 1_{t\geq 0}}+e^{-(-b)t}\sin(\omega _0t),$$
but I can't conclude. Any idea ?

Comment: $u(-t)=0$ for $t>0$.  And the unilateral LT spans $t\ge0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(t) = e^{-bt}\sin(\omega_0t)u(t)$$
Notice that $$f(-t) = -e^{bt}\sin(\omega_0t)u(-t)$$
Laplace transforms have a nice property that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f(-t)\right\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}(-s)$$
Using your known result of
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}(s) = \frac{\omega_0}{(s+b)^2+\omega_0}$$
we can use the property above to see that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f(-t)\right\}(s) = \frac{\omega_0}{(-s+b)^2+\omega_0} = \frac{\omega_0}{(s-b)^2+\omega_0}$$

Comment: I saw that but unfortunately, I don't have any formula for that (sorry, I just use table to compute laplace transform). I'm sure that for a mathematician it's a very good hint, but unfortunately, I don't have formula for that.

Comment: I agree for Fourier transform, but what about Laplace transform ?

Comment: Oops, I read it as Fourier for some reason. It's the same for Laplace transforms. I will change that above.

Comment: Disregard this answer, it is only true for bilateral Laplace transforms, not unilateral. I will submit the answer for deletion shortly.

Comment: I believe the answer is correct. The question is about the two-sided Laplace transform, for which we have $\mathcal L[f(-t)] = F(-p), b=\alpha$.

Comment: @Maxim In that case, I guess it's okay to leave it up.